# What is the fastest possible way to get the first record more than a threshold in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to set up a function such that for each row in one table I get the nearest record greater than that record from another table. These values are datetimes/timestamps.

I made this function, then I package it as follows:

### Important note:

This function assumes the dataframe is sorted

```
def get_closest(dt_value, df, column='DateTime', value_column='SampleNumber'):
    filtered_df = df[df[column] >= dt_value][0:1]
    [sample_number] = filtered_df[value_column].values.tolist()
    return sample_number
```

I then package it as follows

```
def v_get_closest(a, df2):
    return a.apply(lambda x : get_closest(x, df2))
```

I will be applying to billions of rows in a larger Spark application but that is not important to the problem.

Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**:
Table A

```
           Datetime     Value
0   2015-01-25 14:14:23  0.911291
1   2015-01-25 12:25:33  0.396191
2   2015-01-25 14:48:00  0.040370
3   2015-01-25 22:56:34  0.422482
4   2015-01-25 09:11:09  0.314022
5   2015-01-25 17:38:26  0.969917
6   2015-01-25 01:53:39  0.508699
7   2015-01-25 15:58:50  0.972176
8   2015-01-25 16:49:45  0.112304
9   2015-01-25 07:02:37  0.950211
10  2015-01-25 01:50:14  0.729004
11  2015-01-25 08:15:49  0.828108
12  2015-01-25 21:03:15  0.842581
13  2015-01-25 03:31:36  0.694799
14  2015-01-25 05:37:49  0.521695
15  2015-01-25 13:21:42  0.150373
16  2009-01-25 01:12:00  0.502133
```

Table B

```
              DateTime  Key
1  2010-10-13 18:32:00    2
2  2016-05-13 01:12:03    1
```

Usage:

```
#returns the column
v_get_closest(A['datetime'] , B)
```

Expected:

```
           Datetime     Value      Key
0   2015-01-25 14:14:23  0.911291    1
1   2015-01-25 12:25:33  0.396191    1
2   2015-01-25 14:48:00  0.040370    1
3   2015-01-25 22:56:34  0.422482    1
4   2015-01-25 09:11:09  0.314022    1
5   2015-01-25 17:38:26  0.969917    1
6   2015-01-25 01:53:39  0.508699    1
7   2015-01-25 15:58:50  0.972176    1
8   2015-01-25 16:49:45  0.112304    1
9   2015-01-25 07:02:37  0.950211    1
10  2015-01-25 01:50:14  0.729004    1
11  2015-01-25 08:15:49  0.828108    1
12  2015-01-25 21:03:15  0.842581    1
13  2015-01-25 03:31:36  0.694799    1
14  2015-01-25 05:37:49  0.521695    1
15  2015-01-25 13:21:42  0.150373    1
16  2009-01-25 01:12:00  0.502133    2
```

Comment: I don't know how much faster (if at all) that would be but for what it's worth you can skip the lambda: `a.apply(get_closest, args=(df2,))`

Comment: it's hard to measure without a testable dataframe fragments, if you have such - post them

Comment: Also, `[sample_number] = filtered_df[value_column].values.tolist() ; return sample_number` why? just do `return filtered_df[value_column].values.tolist()`

Comment: @DeepSpace to shed off the list and get only the value

Comment: @CollinCunningham so just `return filtered_df[value_column].values[0]` much less overhead than creating 2 lists every single function call

Comment: How are you planning to call `multiply_func`? give us some demo usages including the 2 dataframes and expected output

Comment: @DeepSpace Please see edit. And note I changed the function name for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the 2009 row come into play in the expected results?  To me, this looks like it could be solved with pd.merge_asof.

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='DateTime'),
                   df2.sort_values(by='DateTime'),
                   on='DateTime'
                   direction='forward')
```

Comment: I swapped in 2009 so they all didnt map to 1. I fixed it. Do you know the efficiency of `merge_asof`

Comment: Provided it does what you're looking to do it's expected to be faster than apply.